# TypeError: Device_Data[4] is undefined

Tags: javascript, php

I am fetching few values from database and passing them to a js function as json. For one of the values, I am getting `TypeError: Device_Data[4] is undefined` error. I have tried a lot but not able to resolve the problem.

Here is the query & js function call:

```
 <?php
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("Select date_time, temperature, humidity, pressure, light, rain, solar FROM weather_measurements order by date_time desc limit 12");
    $stmt2->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $WData2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
  ?>
    <script>
      var WData2 = <?php echo(json_encode($WData2));?>;
      dspChrt2(WData2);
    </script>
```

Here is js function where I am receiving data and getting error:

```
   var Device_Data;
   var temperature2, date_time, solar, rain, light, pressure, humidity;


   function dspChrt2(Device_Data) { 
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var date_time_Array = [];
        var temp2_Array = [];
        var humidity_Array = [];
        var pressure_Array = [];
        var light_Array = [];
        var solar_Array = [];
        var rain_Array = [];

        console.log(Device_Data[0].date_time);
        console.log(Device_Data[1].temperature);
        console.log(Device_Data[2].humidity);
        console.log(Device_Data[3].pressure);
        console.log(Device_Data[4].light); //TypeError: Device_Data[4] is undefined 
        console.log(Device_Data[5].rain);
        console.log(Device_Data[6].solar);
```

The indexes are right in order how I am fetching in query and calling in the function. What other reason can be of this error? It's working fine on local server on windows but on ubuntu, it started raising this error.

**EDIT**
var_dump($WData2) on personal web server where it's working

*array(12) { [0]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 19:17:21" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 19:17:21" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 19:12:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [3]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 19:07:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [4]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 19:02:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [5]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 18:57:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [6]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 18:01:20" ["temperature"]=> string(1) "2" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1024) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [7]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 17:56:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "2.1" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1024) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [8]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 17:51:20" ["temperature"]=> string(1) "2" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1024) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [9]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 17:46:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.9" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1024) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [10]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 17:41:20" ["temperature"]=> string(1) "2" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "100" ["pressure"]=> int(1024) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } [11]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-11-01 17:06:20" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "2.3" ["humidity"]=> string(4) "99.1" ["pressure"]=> int(1023) ["light"]=> int(0) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(0) } }*

**EDIT**
var_dump($WData2); on ubuntu where error is

*array(4) { [0]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 11:30:30" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "2.7" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "3.5" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(473) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(111) } [1]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 11:10:30" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "110" ["pressure"]=> int(1025) ["light"]=> int(473) ["rain"]=> int(0) ["solar"]=> int(107) } [2]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 11:00:30" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "6.4" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "117" ["pressure"]=> int(1020) ["light"]=> int(429) ["rain"]=> int(1) ["solar"]=> int(101) } [3]=> array(7) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-13 10:25:30" ["temperature"]=> string(3) "1.8" ["humidity"]=> string(3) "111" ["pressure"]=> int(1030) ["light"]=> int(469) ["rain"]=> int(1) ["solar"]=> int(103) } }*

Comment: What does `$WData2` look like?

Comment: Double check your Ubuntu server database and ensure that column exists.

Comment: First: your query result returns an array of Device_Data which is [Device_Data1, Device_Data2,...] So when you pass the value through dspChrt2 function, you have to loop through that array first. The error could be from your query returns 4 rows only.
Second: each row of your query result is an assoc array, you have to access the value through array keys, which is Device_Data['date_time'], Device_Data['temperature'], etc

Comment: @Zitzabis: I check it carefully, basically these are copy of each other. I first make things working on apache at windows and then transfer to ubuntu.

Comment: @MattWay: I added var_dump of WData2 on both windows where it's working and of ubuntu where it's not working.

Comment: @catcon: You were right. I added more rows then it started working. Thank you :-)

Comment: @XCeptable: No worries :)